# How to loop in R over multiple categorical variables, do calculation and then create plot

Tags: r, loops, categorical-data, survey

I'm new to coding with R and I'm doing some analysis with categorical variables.

My data frame consists of answers from single respondents. I want to analyse the data by area. The data frame looks like this:

```
structure(list(area = c("chicago", "portland", "chicago", "detroit" ), 
               a1 = c("good", "bad", "good", "bad"), 
               a2 = c("good", "bad", "good", "bad"), 
               a3 = c("bad", "bad", "bad", "bad"), 
               weight = c(140.626215, 111.285163, 132.497397, 129.510583), 
               strata = c("male_ch_20", "female_po_40", "male_ch_70", "male_po_30")), 
          row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

What I'm doing so far is this to get the percentage out for all the areas together and each answer individually:

```
my_data_new <- my_data %>%
  group_by(area, answer2) %>%
  summarize(share = survey_mean()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  my_own_function() %>% 
  arrange(answer2)
  my_data_new
```

and then plot this (the y value is produced by my_own_function)

```
ggplot() +  
  geom_bar(data = my_data_new, aes(x = area, y = percentage, fill = answer2), stat = "identity")
```

So far I've been typing manually the answer variable (answer1, then answer2, then answer3 and so on) into the group_by and also into the `ggplot` function but I would like to use a loop to do so.

I've done this to access the individual areas but don't know how to continue from here.

```
list_of_tempdata <- list()
unique_areas <- unique(my_data_new$area)
for(i in 1:length(unique_areas)){
  list_of_tempdata[[i]] <- my_data_new[my_data_new$area==unique_area[i],]
}
```

Comment: Maybe a good approach would be to convert data into long format and show all answers together using `facets`. Can you share `dput(my_data)` ?

Comment: structure(list(area = c("chicago", "portland", "chicago", "detroit"
), a1 = c("good", "bad", "good", "bad"), a2 = c("good", "bad", 
"good", "bad"), a3 = c("bad", "bad", "bad", "bad"), weight = c(140.626215, 
111.285163, 132.497397, 129.510583), strata = c("male_ch_20", 
"female_po_40", "male_ch_70", "male_po_30")), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: It's much easier to work with data that you [edit] into the question instead of leaving in comments. I've done that for you this time. However, it's still unclear what you're trying to do. We can't run this code without having `my_own_function`, and you should note which packages you're using. What's the goal exactly?

Comment: Reading the OP question, I think it is unknown to the OP what is my_own_function..? And that's why this question/post arises..